# How to trigger Automation Pipeline after an Build Pipeline is successfully and only triggered by a specific user

Tags: jenkins, automation, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Suppose Jenkins Build A is Successfully Triggered and after that Automation Pipeline on that Build is to be executed.
The above Scenario is possible using Jenkins Build Triggers using : **Build after other projects are built**

But in addition when we want to trigger Automation only if the build is generated by a specific used
For e.g.
User A, User B, Users C

So the Automation Pipeline must get generated only if the Build Pipeline is triggered by User A and User B.
The Automation Pipeline must not be triggered if the Build is generated by User C.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you have two Jobs, Build
and Automation. If Build Job is triggered by UserA, UserB.... you want to trigger the Automation Job. In order to achieve this, in your Build job, before triggering the Automation Job you can check who triggered the Build Job and decide whether to trigger the Automation job or not. Check the example below.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
       stage ('BuildJob') {
          steps {
            script {
                def userList = ["admin2", "UserA", "UserB", "UserC"]
                def buildTrigger = currentBuild.getBuildCauses('hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause')
                // Here checking username and triggering the automation build
                if(buildTrigger != null && !buildTrigger.userId.disjoint(userList)) {
                    echo "Build the Second JOb========"
                    build job: 'AutomationJob'
                }
                
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value in currentBuild as I will be taking this value from other Pipeline

Comment: @SaurabhKawli Your question is not clear. The `currentBuild` returns a `RunWrapper`  object https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html

Comment: thanks for your help
Can you tell me how do I get the name of the user who triggered a JOB but I want this details in other JOB where I will validate if that user has generated the build or a different user.